# What is the best way to approach any professor for Ph.D. opportunities who my research advisor has referred?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, united-states, email, supervision

I am a final-year undergraduate student, and I worked with a professor for more than a year. I recently asked him for a reference, and there he suggested contacting another professor he knows to look for Ph.D. opportunities in his lab. What can be the best way to email the professor citing the reference of my advisor?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I have edited my query.

Comment: Ok. I don't think it's substantially different from the linked Q

Comment: Kindly do not downvote my question. I am in dire need of answer to this query.

Comment: Yes, I linked a question to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the question you have linked is more generalized instead of being specific.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, I, too, disagree that this is a duplicate. I realize that the question you linked is a bit (but not completely) canonical. Maybe you would like to update that to cover this sort of case.

Comment: Where is the university you would be applying to? If In the US, I'd add a bit to my answer. And see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368 for general information.

Comment: @Buffy I don't feel anything further is needed. If you do, you'd be the better candidate to update.

Comment: @Buffy Yes it is in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Just mention that you were referred by professor A. I wouldn't open with it but would include it quite early so that it isn't missed. Open with your interest. Mention the reference and that it was suggested you contact them directly. Close with some words about your capabilities. Make it short, but also ask what your next steps might be if the person has any interest.

Don't make it long or it is too easy to discard. Offer to send additional information if needed.

Don't use bold font or such for the professors name, but assure that it is placed where a quick look at your mail won't miss it.

Note, however, that, in the US, the only answer you might get is something like "Yes, I'm interested, but you need to apply for admission using the normal procedures." It is rare here that individual professors have a lot to say about admissions and, unlike other places, they seldom "hire" doctoral students directly.

For general information about how the system works here, see the answer for the US to [the canonical question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368)

---

Note that even better would be a note from your professor to the other introducing you. That won't be ignored most likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion